# JQuery appending wrong value with a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was making a page that would calculate and display all the prime numbers from 1 through 100. The actual prime number calculation works fine, but when I tried to append the numbers that tested as primes through JQuery, it would instead append it as the number 101 every single time.

JS code:

```
function primeFinder() {
    var testNum = 1;
    var failures = 0;
    var checkNum = testNum -1;
    while(testNum <= 100) {
        while(checkNum > 1) {
            if ((testNum/checkNum)%1 != 0) {
                failures += 1;
                checkNum -= 1;

                }
            else {
                checkNum -= 1;
                }               
            }
        if (failures == testNum - 2) {
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#results").append(testNum + "<br>")
                })
                failures = 0;
                testNum +=1;
                checkNum = testNum -1;
        }
        else {
            failures = 0;
            testNum +=1;
            checkNum = testNum -1;
        }
    }
}
```

It appends it properly, it's just appending the incorrect value for a reason I can't figure out. If I change the variable to text, it then works no problem. It's just the variable it can't handle correctly.

Comment: Can you made a jsFiddle?

Comment: Please provide whole code... your code looks like pseudo-code: "testNum" is string?

Comment: @sinisake he did it on purpose: "If I change the variable to text, it then works no problem.". To OP, please post your whole code or post a fiddle to make it easier to spot the problem

Comment: @georaldc, yes, you are right... 101 is strange result, anyway...

Comment: Well you are appending the `testNum` variable after document ready, which likely occurs after your loop has finished running. This will result it in printing out the final/last assigned value of `testNum`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment: you are appending `testNum` in each loop, but only after document ready. This results in the final value of `testNum` being appended since the loop is likely to have executed way before the document is ready.

To circumvent this issue, simply wrap your entire function within the DOM ready event, and you should be good to go. Here is a proof-of-concept snippet based on the code you have provided.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   // You can move this function declaration outside DOM ready, doesn't matter
   var primeFinder = function() {
     var testNum = 1;
     var failures = 0;
     var checkNum = testNum - 1;
     while (testNum <= 100) {
       while (checkNum > 1) {
         if ((testNum / checkNum) % 1 != 0) {
           failures += 1;
           // console.log(checkNum + " ~~~ " + failures);
           checkNum -= 1;

         } else {
           checkNum -= 1;
         }
       }
       if (failures == testNum - 2) {
         console.log(testNum + " is prime!");

         $("#results").append(testNum + "<br>")
         failures = 0;
         testNum += 1;
         checkNum = testNum - 1;
       } else {
         // console.log(testNum + " is NOT prime!");
         failures = 0;
         testNum += 1;
         checkNum = testNum - 1;
       }
     }
   }
   
   // But you must execute this function within DOM ready
   primeFinder();
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="results"></div>
```